# html2canvas while updating canvas data

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

plot array is a global variable., 
while console.log the canvas parameter inside the onrendered function .., data exists. but.. when logged outside the function.., gives empty array

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector(".classone"),{
  onrendered:function(canvas){
      plot_array.push({canvasdata:canvas.toDataURL('image/png')});
  }
});

console.log(plot_array);
```

> the plot array logged as empty...
>   **??**

Comment: If I'm right, the `onrendered` function is called once the canvas has been rendered. If you call `console.log` right after `html2canvas`, the canvas will not be rendered yet, and thus nothing is pushed to your `plot_array`.

Comment: Try moving `console.log(plot_array);` inside the `onrendered` function, after the `push`.

Comment: the html2canvas function is actually inside a for loop.., so .,i need all data to be logged after rendered..

Comment: Can't you have it log each loop?  The last one will log the entire array.  The alternative is to run 'console.log' function after the loop has finished.

Comment: iam making an ajax call after the for loop.., so i need that array with exact data..,

Comment: Welcome to js. html2canvas is an asynchronous function. In earlier versions, you had to provide a callback function as a parameter, nowadays, it does use Promises. In any case, you just have to set a counter variable before your calls, and increment it in the callbacks. Once the counter reaches the numbers of calls to be made, all asynchronous functions are done, you can continue to your ajax call. So with your actual code (which uses an old version of h2c) Before the loop : `var rendered = 0;` and then in the loop `h2c(... onrendered: function(){...if(++rendered===calls.length){ajax()})})`

Comment: got that!!>>thanks a lot!!>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to js. html2canvas is an asynchronous function. In earlier versions, you had to provide a callback function as a parameter, nowadays, it does use Promises. In any case, you just have to set a counter variable before your calls, and increment it in the callbacks. Once the counter reaches the numbers of calls to be made, all asynchronous functions are done, you can continue to your ajax call. So with your actual code (which uses an old version of h2c) Before the loop :`var rendered = 0;` and then in the loop `h2c(... onrendered: function(){...if(++rendered===calls.length){ajax()})})`

as answered by **Kaiido**

Answer (score 0):

It's because the rendered event has not been propagated yet. It's perfectly normal and accepted behaviour: you want this array to be filled only when the canvas has finished being drawn.

Comment: any how do i get it.., i.e: how could i able to know when canvas is rendered..??

Comment: well you have to think a bit differently when you do event-based programming. For exemple you will have a "reaction" to this event: showing an alert popup can be a good first one. The logic is that you don't block anymore, waiting for the operation to finish. Can you give a bit more context on what you'd like to do later ?

Comment: the html2canvas function is actually inside a for loop.., so .,i need all data to be logged after rendered.